# Unwanted double click on my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building my website portfolio as a student website designer but literally cant figure out as to why when clicking on items on the homepage it makes you double click. You can click once anywhere and then click on what you want once like there is a layer on top of the page that you need to click on first or something.

As I don't know were the problem is i cant upload the code for the whole of my site so here is the whole site in a zip:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/n695ote8nbeol96/Portfolio%20Website.zip?dl=0

Or you can view the source on my website at:

http://www.liam-dean.com

website is half done so don't worry if things are missing.

Many thanks.

Comment: link is taking too long to load, what specifically requires a double click? link, onclick event? You need to show the code here really so it can be answered and helps others.

Comment: can you not download the dropbox file of it? theres a good couple of thousand lines of code so couldn't really post it all!

Comment: I wouldnt go to that much effort either, usually you focus on one element, its likely to be the same issue with most of the elements and post the code for that. But use the page inspector/ conole in chrome to discover whats happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in coreweb-ui.js:

```
if( $(".navigation").css("margin-left") != 0 ){
    closeMenu();
}
```

It looks like you want to close the navigation if it is open but there is no element in the DOM that matches '.navigation'.

You should change this to check there is an element with the class "navigation" and that the element's margin is not 0:

```
if( $('.navigation').length && $(".navigation").css("margin-left") != 0 ){
    closeMenu();
}
```

Comment: omfg yes thank you!! javascript is my weakness and that did work! thank you so so much sir!

Comment: You can and should use the chrome developer tools to track down issues like this. It is a tool worth learning if you're going to be doing web related work.

Answer (score 2):

You have this function in the coreweb-ui.js which is throwing an error the first time you click on the images:

```
function closeMenu(){
    $("#portfolio, .cover, .page, .navigation, .bigBg").animate({'margin-left' : '0px'}, 500, 'easeOutExpo');
    $(".btMenu").attr('modo','off');
}
```

this line errors out the first time:

```
$("#portfolio, .cover, .page, .navigation, .bigBg").animate({'margin-left' : '0px'}, 500, 'easeOutExpo');
```

}

and then there is another bug in the same file:
event:

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
```

this condition is missing a `=`

```
} else if (destino = "_mail") {
```

the error that you see in the console stops the page from navigating the first time:

```
Uncaught TypeError: f.easing[i.animatedProperties[this.prop]] is not a function
```

Comment: I am no javascript pro at all and jsut downloaded this js file, any easy solution to fixing these problems without knowing js or?